# Two ways of time series cross-validation for ARIMA giving different results

Tags: r, time-series, cross-validation, arima

I have data `x` that I have split into `train` and `test` data:

```
train = x[1:80,1]
test = x[81:length(x), 1]
```

I am trying to do cross-validation: i.e. fit the model to `train` and then see how it performs compared to the `test` data.

The first method I'm using is through the `Arima()` function:

```
fittrain = Arima(train, order=c(1,1,0))
fittest = Arima(test, model=fittrain)
accuracy(fittest)

> accuracy(fittest)
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE      MAPE      MASE
Training set 346.2611 414.9891 353.2179 0.1926218 0.1965906 0.2973771
                   ACF1
Training set -0.1857537
```

I wanted to confirm that this is indeed comparing the fitted model to my test data:

```
fit = Arima(train, order=c(1,1,0))
preds = as.vector(forecast(fit, h = length(test))$mean)
RMSE = sqrt(mean((preds - as.vector(testdata)) ^ 2))
RMSE

> RMSE
[1] 4022.871
```

Why am I getting such different values for the RMSE? Is there a function that will compare my model forecasts to the actual test data values and give me a bunch of different metrics?

Comment: You would normally use the same function (either `arima` or `Arima` but not both) when comparing the two cases to avoid any of the discrepancies being due to the different functions used. Most likely they will deliver the same results, but it is safer to use the same function in both cases just in case.

Comment: Good point. I edited my post. In the second scenario `arima` and `Arima` do indeed give the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **case 1**, you are looking at in-sample fit in the test sample from a model whose coefficients were optimized for the training sample rather than the test sample. I.e. you look at properties of residuals $\Delta y_t-\widehat{\Delta y}_t$ for $t$ running in the test sample where $\widehat{\Delta y}_t=\hat\varphi_1 \Delta y_{t-1}$ where $\hat\varphi_1$ is the fitted coefficient based on the training sample.

In **case 2**, you at looking at forecast errors from forecasts of an increasingly longer horizon. I.e. $y_{T+h}-\widehat{\Delta y}_{T+h}$ where $\widehat{\Delta y}_{T+h}=(\hat\varphi_1)^h y_T$ where $y_T$ is the last point in the training sample and $T+h$ runs in the test sample.

Clearly, you expect a much better in-sample fit in **case 1** even though the coefficients were optimized on a different sample, as long as the data generating process has not changed from the training to the test sample, and a much worse forecast accuracy in **case 2** since the forecasts are of an increasingly longer horizon. This is exactly what you have observed.

Comment: To put this in words, if I understand correctly, as we get farther in time **case 1** makes predictions 1 step ahead using the true test values as input, whereas **case 2** makes predictions using previous predictions as input? Which of these methods are used in practice? My instinct is that **case 2** provides a more realistic approach, since this is how forecasts will be handled. But if this is true, why isn't `accuracy()` programmed to work this way?

Comment: @theQman, Your understanding of cases 1 and 2 are correct. I would not say that that either case 1 or case 2 is particularly realistic. What could be a more realistic scenario is when you forecast $h$ steps ahead, then your sample expands by one extra observation, then you forecast $h$ steps ahead again, then the sample expands again, etc. This is how forecasting is normally done in macroeconomics and finance. Thus effectively you have expanding samples, but your forecast horizon does not change (the time flows but you are always interested in the GDP next quarter or stock price next day).